# bootstrap carousel event 'slide.bs.carousel' gets fired only ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('#carousel-container').bind("slide.bs.carousel", function () {
    //reset
    $('.slideImg',this).css('min-height', '');
    //set
    var sliderHeight = $(this).height();
    $(this).css('min-height', sliderHeight + 'px');
    $(this).off("slide.bs.carousel");
    //set the max size for img
    $('.slideImg').css('max-height', (sliderHeight * 0.9) + 'px');
    $('#Hand_Side').css('max-height', (sliderHeight * 0.4) + 'px');
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-container" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">

                            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div id="slide1" class="item active">
                                </div>
                                <div id="slide3" class="item">
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
```

I am not sure why, but the event only get fired ones before sliding the first slide.

Answer (score 1):

i see i missed this line

```
$(this).off("slide.bs.carousel");
```

this line turned off the event it should not fire anymore